# Does Vuepress have access to the @ or ~ symbols used in Vue paths?

Tags: vuepress

Does Vuepress have access to the @ or ~ symbols used in Vue paths?

I mean can I do something like:

```
import Hello from '@/components/Hello'
```

rather than

```
import Hello from '../../components/Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has just changed to reflect this:

https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown.html#import-code-snippets

```
TIP

Since the import of the code snippets will be executed before webpack compilation, you can't use the path alias in webpack. The default value of @ is process.cwd().
```